# tocloft conditional spacing

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, chapters, tocloft

This is my first question on stackexchange!

I am using the tocloft package for my thesis and my university requires doublespacing before and after the chapter titles in the ToC, but only if the chapter has sections.

I am thinking that I will require some way to detect if the chapter has sections, or add a newline before the first section in each chapter. Can somebody suggest a way to achieve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Am I correct that there should be additional vertical space before/after chapter titles *in the table of contents?* (You added the [tag:tocloft] tag, but did not mention the ToC in your actual question.)

Comment: BTW, you don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: Thanks lockstep! There should be additional space after the chapter title if the chapter has sections within it. The section titles themselves are single spaced.

I have \setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{\baselineskip} but this only helps me in adding space before section titles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your question, you can use the `etoolbox` package to hook to the `\section` command to add a vertical spacing in the ToC if the section counter is one:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\preto\section{%
  \ifnum\value{section}=0\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip10pt}\fi
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter with sections}
\section{Section one one}
\section{Section one two}
\chapter{A chapter without sections}
\chapter{Another chapter with sections}
\section{Section one one}
\section{Section one two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Nikhil Gupta: Hmm... now that I see my answer, this surely is not what you need, or is it?

Comment: However, the correct code is 
`
\preto\section{%
  \ifnum\value{section}=1\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip10pt}\fi
}`

Comment: @NikhilGupta: are you sure? If so, then I didn't fully understand your question.

Comment: In the version that you composed, you were adding extra space in the else condition so it would add space before all sections except the first. That's the only modification I made.

Comment: @NikhilGupta: maybe I am misunderstanding you, but the code I posted produces the result illustrated in the attached image; i.e., extra space before the first section.

Comment: @NikhilGupta: ah, you're right. Somehow I posted a test code and forgot to change the conditional. I'll edit my answer.